# Devise not current_user method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I'm new to devise and I haven't been able to find a solution to this problem: I want to get/show all posts **not** associated with a user when that user is signed in.

I have the following model associations:

**user.rb**

```
has_many :posts
```

and **post.rb**

```
belongs_to :user
```

How might I do this? I'm looking for something along the lines of:

```
- not_current_user.posts.all.each do |post|
  = post.foo
  = post.bar
```

Is there some method or approach which might accomplish something like this?

If I'm not being clear or if I happened to miss an answer for this please let me know.

Cheers

Comment: Don't you mean: `user.rb`: `has_many :posts` and `post.rb`: `belongs_to :user`?

Comment: @User089247 I do - thanks! I've edited my post accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am guessing you probably mean:

**user.rb**: `has_many :posts` and **post.rb**: `belongs_to :user`

You can try this:

```
@posts = Post.where.not(user_id: current_user.id)
```

then in view:

```
- @posts.each do |post|
  = post.foo
  = post.bar
```

Comment: Thank you - yeah sorry I did mean that (and I have edited my post to reflect it).

Regarding your reply - that sounds like it will do that trick! Good idea and thank you

Answer (score 1):

Use `posts =  Post.where('user_id != ?', current_user.id)`

Then `posts.each do ...`

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, I would recommend not using this type of logic in the view. It is best to have this logic elsewhere, and just render the posts object in the view. This decouples your view logic from your model and controller logic.

To get to posts NOT associated with the user, now you can just query the database

```
# app/controllers/posts_controller.rb
@posts = Posts.where.not(user_id: current_user.id)     # syntax for Rails 4.0+
```

Comment: Yeah - I'll be sure to take your advice and revoce the logic from the view, thank you! 

As a side note - do you know what the rails 4 syntax would be for what you suggested? Cheers

Comment: My comment was confusing. This IS the syntax (`where.not`) for Rails 4.

Answer (score 1):

Probably with something like this:

post.rb

```
scope :all_other_than_created_by_user -> { |user| where(['user_id != ?', user.id]) }
```

In controller:

```
@posts = Post.all_other_than_created_by_user(current_user)
```

And use it in view like:

```
- @posts.each do |post|
  = post.foo
  = post.bar
```

Edit: I changed it to actually do database query in controller, it's better than doing it in view.

Comment: Is it better to use the 'scope in the model' approach or just to use the controller to posts = Post.all_other_than_created_by_user(current_user)? Is there a performance difference at all?

Comment: It's better to use scope approach. Don't think about performance, think about separating layers of MVC.

Comment: So the scope (filter) would go in the model because that is the area of rails which handles server data and it would be the most basic place to implement the limitation. Plus it is generally better to keep the controller thin - is that all right? Thanks for the advice and help!

Comment: @VoA - yep, exactly :)